# Pass Model data to ajax request url for dataTables

Tags: javascript, ajax, datatables, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

I am trying to pass the @Model.Id from my razor view to the javascript so that I can pass it to the dataTables ajax url but I cant manage to get the value to the javascript file.
Even just a point in the right direction would help at this point

**Here is the View:**

```
    @model GTravel.Domain.Package    
    @{
        var title = Model.Name;    
    }


   //boring html code


    @section Scripts{
        <script src="~/js/packageCity.js" data-packageId="@Model.Id"></script>
    }
```

**And a snippet of the js:**

```
var dataTable;
var url;
$(document).ready(function () {
    url = "/admin/packageCity/GetAll/" + packageId.toString();
    loadDataTable();
});



function loadDataTable() {

    dataTable = $('#tblData').DataTable({
        "ajax": {
            "url": url,
            "type": "GET",
            "datatype": "json"
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "city", "width": "10%" },            

//more code etc
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your method, you are missing some key content.

To ensure that the value passed by `data-packageId` can be accurately obtained in the js file, **you need to add an id to the script that references the js file**, and then obtain the passed value by obtaining the corresponding id in the js file:

```
  @section Scripts{
        <script  id="Index.js"  src="~/js/packageCity.js" data-packageId="@Model.Id"></script>
    }
```

js file:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $vars = $('#Index\\.js').data();
    url = "/admin/packageCity/GetAll/" + $vars.packageid;
    loadDataTable();
});
```

And it should be noted that when obtaining the packageId through $vars, make sure that the packageId are all **lowercase letters**.

Another method:

**You can create a variable in the view directly before referencing the js file**, and then accept the value that needs to be passed, so that in the js file, you can directly call the variable to get the value that needs to be passed.

```
@section Scripts{
    <script> 
    var data = '@Model.Id'; 
    </script>
    <script  src="~/js/packageCity.js" ></script>

}
```

js file:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

        url = "/admin/packageCity/GetAll/" + data;
        loadDataTable();
    });
```